# Are "Get Paid to Travel" ads part of a sex trafficking network?

Tags: sexuality, employment

Recently, on Facebook, the following images have been trending in my feed, people forwarding them on, claiming that most if not all of them are actually attempts to get women into sex trafficking (click to embiggen):

[image: Now Hiring image] [image: Get Paid to Travel image] [image: Afterschool Jon image]

I'm a bit skeptical, both because some of the posts unironically invoke [Pizzagate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzagate_conspiracy_theory) and because this sounds like the sort of thing that would be in an urban legend, [people being sent to a location to find work](http://www.snopes.com/horrors/madmen/lastone.asp) and getting suspicious, and it turning out that it was a way to lure them into being commoditized. Lastly, the evidence for this being sex trafficking seems to largely be reports of calling the number for details and getting someone with a foreign accent who hangs up when they ask for more details, which sounds more like a general scam than sex trafficking.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Is this a photo of an actual ad posted by sex traffickers?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37696/is-this-a-photo-of-an-actual-ad-posted-by-sex-traffickers/37698)

Comment: @tim: I thought I remembered something like this popping up, but I could not find it via search. I'll give it a day or two to see if there's more information based on added images.

Comment: Doing a google search for the number in the third picture gives a whole bunch of people claiming that it's a sex trafficing ring, but it's all just reposts of the facebook post in the image.

Comment: The first two look more like they're recruiting drug mules than sex slaves.

Comment: The tagging is weird: According to dictionary definitions, sex trafficking has as much to do with sexuality as slavery has with personal hobbies, or murder with sleeping. One describes a crime, the other a person’s voluntary pastime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Best match I could find. "Use this tag for the psychological and **social aspects of sex and sexual activities** in general."

Comment: I've been paid to travel for years, to and from the customers' offices as an IT consultant. Was I being sex trafficked without knowing it?

Comment: @jwenting: Was it as a result of answering an ad such as these, or was it under the aegis of a company's work?

Comment: @SeanDuggan never responded to such an ad, but just saying that job offers including travel don't necessarily have to be by sex trafficking gangs. Most in fact won't be, they can be anything from what I was, a technical consultant, to a sales representative, to my dad (may he rest in peace) who was CEO for international relations for a multinational.

Comment: @jwenting: And admittedly, they could be more garden-variety scams ranging from unaware drug mules to the opportunity requiring purchasing a kit or attending a seminar and then mysteriously, the opportunities dry up. I'm starting to think that maybe this question is too broad because there really are too many possibilities.